# Create and execute stored procedure in SQL Server with parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have four tables:

- dbo.Projects (id, ProjectName, Areas, PaymentSystem, Districts.id, purpose.id, types.id, etc)
- dbo.Districts(id, DistrictsName)
- dbo.Purpose (id, PurposeName) - has residential & commercial
- dbo.Types (id, typName)

I want to select projects where DistrictsName='District1' and PurposeName = 'residential'

I tried this procedure :

```
alter PROCEDURE GetProjects
    @districtName nvarchar(50),
    @purposeName nvarchar(50)
as
    SELECT 
        p.ID, p.ProjectName,  p.Areas, 
        p.PaymentSystem, p.ReceivedDate,    
        p.PropertyClassification, 
        p.ProjectImage,         
        dis.DistrictName,
        Pur.PurposeName            
    FROM 
        dbo.Projects AS p 
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.Districts dis ON p.DistrictID = dis.ID   
    LEFT JOIN  
        dbo.Purpose pur ON p.PurposeID = pur.ID 
    WHERE 
       (dis.DistrictName = @districtName) 
       AND (Pur.PurposeName = @purposeName)

exec GetProjects @districtName='District1', @purposeName='residential '
```

When I execute this procedure, it returns with null - no data is returned.

**Note**: database supported Arabic language

When I execute this query it returns the result I think no data returned because Arabic language

```
SELECT 
    p.ID, p.ProjectName, p.Areas, 
    p.PaymentSystem, p.ReceivedDate,    
    p.PropertyClassification, 
    p.ProjectImage,         
    dis.DistrictName,
    Pur.PurposeName            
    FROM 
        dbo.Projects AS p 
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.Districts dis ON p.DistrictID = dis.ID   
    LEFT JOIN  
        dbo.Purpose pur ON p.PurposeID = pur.ID 
    WHERE 
        (dis.DistrictName = N'arabic value') 
        AND (Pur.PurposeName = N'arabic value')
```

Comment: How about remove the last blank character in purposename? `...,@purposeName='residential'`

Comment: And you might as well change the two `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`. The `WHERE` clause turn them to `INNER JOIN` any way.

Comment: still no data return when i remove `...,@purposeName='residential'`

Comment: Do you have any data where the districtname = 'District1'? I don't see anything wrong with your query so it must be data.

Comment: Try running the query independently (outside the stored procedure) to see if you have any data?

Comment: i update my question

Comment: Then run your stored procedure with this: `exec GetProjects @districtName=N'arabic value',@purposeName=N'arabic    value'` and see if you get result? The problem might be in the Unicode things.

Comment: yes it gives me the result

Answer (score 1):

Use this execution command

```
exec GetProjects @districtName=N'arabic value',@purposeName=N'arabic    value'
```

Put the N in front to indicate you are using Unicode.

Comment: this command return the result i want but i want to remove this static value and make it parameter

Comment: Keep the stored procedure "as is" (as in as before you posted the question). Then run it using the parameter `@districName=N'<<your value here>>>', @purposeName=N'<<<your value here>>>'`. If it does not return value, you do not have value for that parameter. Simple as that.